# vba module.find with line breaks (Ms access 2013)

Tags: vba, ms-access, module, ms-access-2013, vbe

I have been using a piece of code to find specific text within vba modules.

It works well for finding a single line (or less) of text.
So, for example it will find 'mySub' in a module with text :

```
Private sub mySub() 
  Dim a as Integer  
  Dim b as Integer  
End Sub
```

The code I am using:

```
Set m = myAp.Modules(name)
m.find(text_find, 1, 1, -1, -1, False, False, False)
```

The problem begins when I want to search for multi-line texts.
For example I want to find the section of text:

> Dim a as Integer
>   Dim b as Integer

Unfortunately the find function is returning a false when I try presenting my multi-line search text.

Using debug (watch/immediate) I confirmed that my search criteria (text_find) does contain chrs 13 + 10 in between the first 'Integer' and the  'Dim b'.

I also examined the module.Line value for the "Dim a" line, and that also ends with chrs 13 + 10.

So now I am really struggling to know how to get this working.

If anyone has any help on this - would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I can't get this to work too. `.Find("Dim a as Integer*Dim b as Integer", y1, x1, y2, x2, PatternSearch:=True)` doesn't work either. It may be impossible - but then the `EndLine` parameter would be sort of pointless.

Comment: Did you use instr instead of find keyword to search a word ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't search across more than one line of code using the `Find` method, but you can read all of the lines into a string, and then use `InStr` to locate each occurrence of the search terms:

```
Option Compare Database

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

Sub test()

  Const search As String = "Dim a As Integer" & vbCrLf & "Dim b As Integer"

  Dim md As Module
  Set md = Modules("Module1")

  Dim allLines As String
  allLines = md.Lines(1, md.CountOfLines)

  'Get the first instance of the search term...
  Dim pos As Long
  pos = InStr(1, allLines, search, vbTextCompare)

  Dim found As Boolean
  found = pos > 0

End Sub
```

You should note however, that parsing VBA with Find or InStr is going to be next to impossible. You need a state machine to do it reliably, or you need a library like ANTLR.

Consider a module that contains:

```
Dim a      As Integer 'some comment _
some comment
Dim b _
  As _
  Integer 'Some other comment
```

How do you write a search term that can handle that???

FYI - The Rubberduck VBA project (to which I contribute) has been refining a VBA grammar that can parse nearly all VBA syntax.

Comment: Damn you're evil. OP probably doesn't need to account for all possible wicked ways VBA supports a `Dim` statement to be written though.

Comment: Indeed, but `Dim a     As Integer 'TODO - Give this var a better name` is evil *enough* to be problematic.